# How to get type of `rootReducer`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js, redux-immutable

I have a configured project with `React`, `Redux`, `Immutable.js` + `TypeScript`. During implementation I was trying to declare types as much as possible and found interesting issue. See code example below:

Short configuration of redux store

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({...});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Somewhere inside component

```
// ...
const mapStateToProps = (state: ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>) => {
  // state is plain object :(
};
```

On state hover in VS Code, tooltip shows that state is a plain object, however it is not. It should be a custom collection from `Immutable.js`

How can I get a correct type of `rootReducer`? Or what I am doing wrong?

Screenshots:

[image: Hovered mouse over state variable]

[image: Hovered mouse over emphasized get method]

P.S. `StateType` and `ReturnType` do the same stuff

Answer (score 2):

This works (no need for Immutable.js):

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

If for some reason it does not works, this one should work:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on finding a solution of how to make `TypeScript` work with `Immutable.js` in pair and unfortunately there is no explicit/trivial solution (or I didn't find it).

If you on the start of your project and looking for some alternatives I would highly recommend you to take a look at the [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library. It provides mostly the same functionality and perfectly supports `TypeScript` typings.